# How to expand a paper's width to a maximum width but maintain it flexible?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-design, material-ui

In a React application using Material-UI, how a paper's width can be always expanded to a maximum of 600px regardless if its contents have a width of less or more than 600px, but keep the paper flexible, so when the paper's parent container's width shrinks to less than 600px, the paper shrinks its own width along the parent as well?

Currenty I have:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    ...theme.mixins.gutters(),
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2
  },
});
```

...

```
<Grid container className={classes.root}>
  <Grid container justify="center">
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
    </Paper>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Specifying a fixed width of 600px for the paper doesn't get the desired results, because when the paper's parent width shrinks to less than 600px (e.g. the browser is horizontally downsized) the no-longer-flexible paper remains rigid to 600px width.

Comment: did you tried width:auto? that should automatically expand and shrink

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of setting `width` to "100%" and `maxWidth` to 600.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    ...theme.mixins.gutters(),
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 600
  },
});
```

[image: Edit km2l7l30qr]